# Submenu not appearing vertical

Tags: css, submenu

I've been fighting with this for probably 6 hours now and am completely stumped.  I can't get the submenu to appear vertical on mouse hover.  Here's the link from cssdesk.  What am I messing up?  I know it's something really simple.

http://www.cssdesk.com/n8WCm

If the link doesn't work for you, please see this snippet:

```
.nav8 ul .sub-menu{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.nav8 li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    background:#000;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
}
```

If there is more that you need, please let me know.

Comment: Cssdesk doesn't seem to work at all (at least in my Google Chrome). Paste the code here in a Snippet.

Comment: .nav8 ul .sub-menu{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
}

.nav8 li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 display: block;
 background:#000;
 border: 1px solid #ececec;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add To your Css

```
.nav8 ul li li{
    clear:both;
}
.nav8 ul li ul{
    width:20% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make it not floated left like the main menu, so i would suggest to clear it after every submenu li and give it a fixed width

```
  .nav8 li:hover ul.sub-menu li {
       clear:both;
       width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it have a padding instead of the fixed width?  I have some that will require as much as 400px and others as few as 100px.  Just trying to get some uniformity

Comment: you can add a class so you have .sub-menu li.small { width: 100px;
    } or sub-menu li.large { width: 400px;
    }